# how can i implement a progress bar for training a neural network

Tags: python, user-interface, conv-neural-network, progress-bar

I'm developing a python UI with tkinter for transfer learning of a previously trained network. I currently have 2 python scripts, one for training and one for UI. I set a fixed number of epochs to make it easier for me, but how do I redirect the progress of the training progress into the UI. Do I merge the 2 scripts into one? and I develop a custom callback that updates the bar? or is it possible to keep the scripts separate and do the same thing?
The training is done with tensorflow.
I expect the training to progress and the progress bar to update. I fixed a fixed number of epochs.
EDIT 1
I would that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttdR0.png)

become
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3ifo.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.